Why do Wildfly books same amount of memory in Linux when we put max heap space?
Give 10GB max heap space and restarted server group
and when checked linux free -h then found 10GB gets booked by wildfly.

Is it theoretically correct?
The issue is What if i need to implement scaleup and scale down stuff in Azure Infrastructure? I have 11 wildfly Server Groups with 6gb or so each. So i need to go for reservation due to this behavior. Any suggestions

This is really more of a JDK question, rather than WildFly one.
While the -Xmx does set the maximum heap space, the total amount of memory allocated by the OS will be higher as you need to count in memory requirements for metaspace, thread stacks, code cache, GC and runtime overhead and native libraries and buffers.
If you want to dynamically scale depending on the heap size usage, you cannot rely on the OS, e.g. free. For instance, when you don't use dynamic heap resizing (by setting -Xms), the numbers reported by the OS will not change substantially. You could use tools like jstat -gc <pid> 1000 for that.
